# Learned Loss Attenuation for Classification

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, uncertainty

In the paper [What Uncertainties Do We Need in Bayesian Deep Learning for Computer Vision?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04977.pdf) they propose loss functions that capture aleatoric uncertainty. My question heavily relies on understanding of this paper, so I can go straight to the question without the details. They suggest the following loss objective for regression, where the network outputs two values [ŷ, σ²]:
[image: regression objective]

This allows the model to learn to output a large variance in order to attenuate the loss whenever there's aleatoric uncertainty.

Now, my question is, can the same principle be used for a classification loss? In the paper they end up defining a more complex loss function, but why not just do the same thing as they did for regression? Just replacing the Mean Squared Error for a classification loss like this:
[image]

Doesn't the same logic apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motivation of Bayesian methods is that they allow you to characterize the model in probabilistic terms. In the case of a Gaussian likelihood, the model in the paper allows you to treat each observation $i$ has its own Gaussian r.v. with a mean $\hat y_i$ and a variance $\hat\sigma_i^2$. Then you can answer probabilistic questions about the model's predictions, e.g. "What is the probability that $0 < y_j < 2$?"

The first expression you write is the cross-entropy (negative log-likelihood) for a normal distribution where both the mean and variance are estimated from the data.

The second expression you write does not appear to be a probability distribution. Even if we substitute the standard classification loss $\sum_k y_{ik} \log p_{ik}$ where $\sum_k p_{ik}=1$ and $0 \le p_{ik}$ and $y_{ik}$ as one-hot vector, the loss does not correspond to a probability distribution unless we fix $\hat \sigma_i=1$ for all $i$.

There's no particular reason that neural networks must be probability models (see e.g. [triplet-loss](/questions/tagged/triplet-loss) networks). But in the context of the paper, you would not have a probabilistic interpretation of the model's predictions, because the second loss is not a probability model.

The reason that the authors introduce the "more complex loss function" is to add a source of noise to corrupt model predictions in a way that doesn't change the probability model for the labels.

Comment: I see, I was not aware that those outputs then already have direct probalistic meaning. I was completely focused on the "loss attenuation" aspect, which from my understanding lets the model learn to exclude noisy/conflicting observations from the loss function,. This results in "cleaner" learning and having an indicator for aleatoric uncertainty. I assume one could then still use that indicator ("variance", uncertainty) in a non-probalistic non-Gaussian way, such as just empirically searching for useful thresholds of that value. This then might still apply to that loss function I made up.

Comment: It's an interesting question, whether there exists a non-probabilistic formulation for loss attenuation. I'm not aware of one. I don't think it's impossible, but it would mean adopting a different framework to do so. The authors chose a Bayesian framework, so your proposal is just not something that the paper does.